# How to start a JavaFX Application by shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, javafx

I want to start my java fx application by a shell script. The script should compile the classes and execute the application and include the jar files.
I am currently using JavaFX `Version 8.0.111`.
Do you have any ideas how such a script could look like?

My project structure looks like that:

[image]

Comment: So you mean you want to distribute your application with it's sourcecode instead the compiled package? Maybe you can describe your goal a bit more precise, currently I don't understand what you want to archieve

Comment: could you write down how you compile your programm at the moment? Are you using an IDE to let it compile? Are you familiar with build tools like gradle, maven or ant?
And what do you want to have? Do you want to have .class files you need to execute, a jar archive (with the information which class contains the main or not) and should the jar archive contain all libraries?